# Create a tab for each row found in db

Tags: c#, tabs, oledb

I have a query that selects a table form my db and displays it on some labels, but if the query finds more the one data row it has to display each one of them in a different tab of the form, how can i archive this.

Code:

```
try
{
    mycon.Open();

    string querieslabels = "Select *From Alerts where State = @state && Lv =@lv";

    oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(querieslabels, mycon);

    oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@state", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Open";
    oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@lv", OleDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = "1";

    OleDbDataReader read1;

    read1 = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();

    read1.Read();

    state = read1[4].ToString();

    if (state != "Closed")
    {
        lblNum.Text = read1[0].ToString();
        lblpress.Text = read1[1].ToString();
        txtDescription.Text = read1[2].ToString();
        lblDate.Text = read1[3].ToString();

        lblOk.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        mycon.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        //Hides labels and other control's
        MakeNotVisible();

        MessageBox.Show("No alert found");
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
    }
    finally 
    { 
        mycon.Close(); 
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to create is some alert system, if there is more than 1 alert it should display in a different tab. Can some one guide me to the solution for this, any help or suggestion is appreciated.

NOTE: I'm using Win Form.

Comment: You should create a UserControl, with code that can display one record from a DataTable. Then you can create TabPages and add one new UC to it for each of your rows. Take care not to add too many pages, say no more than 10-20!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with UC, I tried it and i have trouble accessing the fields of the UC from the form, do you know any good guides on UC for WinForms.

Comment: I just added code to work with a DataReader. Tell me if it works for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `UserControl`, with code that can display one record from a `DataTable`. Then you can create `TabPages` and add one new UC to it for each of your rows. Take care not to add too many pages, say no more than 10-15!

**Update** I just noticed that you are using a `DataReader`, not a `DataTable`. No problem, the same solution will worke here, too: Use the added `ShowReader` method and call it like below..!

Here is an example:

```
public partial class DataForm : UserControl
{
    public DataTable theTable { get; set; }

    public DataForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

     public int  showTableRow(int rowIndex)
     {
         if (theTable == null) return -1;
         if (theTable.Rows.Count < rowIndex) return -2;

         DataRow row = theTable.Rows[rowIndex];
         label1.Text = row[0].ToString();
         label2.Text = row[1].ToString();
         label3.Text = row[2].ToString();

         return 0;
     }

    public void showReaderRow(OleDbDataReader DR)
    {
        label1.Text = DR[0].ToString();
        label2.Text = DR[1].ToString();
        label3.Text = DR[2].ToString();
    }
}
```

For easier access we'll keep a List:

```
List<DataForm> theDataPages = new List<DataForm>();
```

Now we can add DataForm pages to the `Tab` control `tabFormPages` from the records in a `DataTable`; here I limit the number to 5:

```
for (int r = 0; r < DTL.Rows.Count && r < 5; r++)
{
    TabPage page = new TabPage( (r+1).ToString("Record #0" ));
    DataForm aForm = new DataForm();
    aForm.theTable = DTL;
    aForm.Parent = page;
    aForm.showTableRow(r);
    tabFormPages.TabPages.Add(page);
    theDataPages.Add(aForm);
}
```

For use with a `DataReader` you could write a read loop like this:

```
while (DR.Read()) 
{
    TabPage page = new TabPage("Alert #" 
                 + (tabFormPages.TabPages.Count+1).ToString());
    DataForm aForm = new DataForm();
    aForm.Parent = page;
    aForm.showReaderRow(DR);
    tabFormPages.TabPages.Add(page);
    theDataPages.Add(aForm);
}
```

First you add the class to your project: `Add - Add Usercontrol`.

Now you can open it in the Designer and put in all `Labels` you need as well as the and put a the code. Also flesh out the `showRow` method to properly display your data in those `Labels`..

Now you can add such UCs to `TabPages` in your `Tab` like I did above.

If you are using a `DataTable` you can also make one page display a certain record by calling the `showRow` again:

```
theDataPages[0].showRow(DTL.Rows.Count - 1);
```

This will show the last record in the first `TabPage`.

If you really need to access field on that UC you can create public properties for those fields and access them like so:

```
    public DataTable theTable { get; set; }
    public Label Label1 { get; set; }
    //..

    public DataForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label1 = label1;
        //..
    }
```

Now you can access the field(s):

```
    if (theDataPages[0].Label1.Text == "Hiho" 
        theDataPages[0].Label1.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: You are Awesome @TaW, I managed to edit your code that suits my needs, works perfectly, just one question, witch is better to use a datatable o a reader? (this might be opinion based) or what are the difference between them? I'm currently using the Reader.

Comment: Both have pros and cons. The reader is for reading sequentially: good for large numbers of records, not good for random access. The DataTable holds all the information locally; good for editing and writing things back, not a problem for medium size or small amounts of data. In your case, I don't see how it makes a big difference..

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a WinForms application or a WebForms application? You might need an Accordion control (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416521/Easy-WinForms-Accordion-Control) or a Tab Control (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/C-Sharp-tabcontrol/) or something similar. You can dynamically create the tabs in them based on the number of rows in your result.

Comment: Im using winform with tab control, i have read about dynamically create tabs, it just i cant figure out how display the information in each tab